# how to model vertex and edge in Moqui entity

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, moqui

Found that Moqui can work with OrientDB. Being new to both Moqui and graph database, my question is: how to put Vertex and edge in Moqui's entity? I mean, in RDMS, If I want to record different people, I can put some thing like:

```
<entity entity-name="Person" package-name="person">
    <field name="personId" type="id" is-pk="true"/>
    <field name="name" type="text-long"/>
```

If I want to creat vertex of different person in OrientDB, how to write the entity?

And how to creat edge in XML code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use OrientDB through the Entity Facade you can use it only as a simple relational structure in the document database in OrientDB. To use full document, graph, and other Orient functionality you have to use the API directly.

There are still few standards for structures and APIs in document, graph, and other NoSQL databases so the best approach is to use the API of a given database rather than using an abstraction layer like the Entity Facade.